# No option to create 'custom apps/tabs' in business page?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add a page tab, or sometimes referred to as custom app/tab to our Facebook Business Page but when I log into our account I can't find the option anywhere.

I am logged in with the "manager" role, which actually is the only account for the page.

I can log into my own personal facebook account and create all the apps for the pages I manage no problem, but the difference is I want to create tabs/app pages for this business page I'm working on.

Please any help would be appreciated, I can't believe how hard it is to find any information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its of any help in your case but you could try the following, just replace "YOUR_APP_ID" and "YOUR_URL" with the ID and URL of the app you want to add as a tab.

"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL"

Source.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Example

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=102452128776&next=https://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/

The above example will give you the option to add "Farmville" to a page that you manage.

Comment: Thx. I need the custom tab to appear on the facebook business page however, so the link in in itself is not really the issue.

Comment: Are you able to add an app to the page but it is not showing up? I have just now added an app to one of my pages and it seems to work just fine, for me anyway, might be the page type, have you the Page Tab URL's in the developers section filled in? sorry I can't be of more help.